# How can I add particular component(like Input component) in Ag-grid by Row wise or how can i remove component by Row in Ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid

How can I add a particular component (like Checkbox, Input , select, dropdown component) in a particular row? Whenever I add a component into columns, it comes in every row. How can I remove the component from a particular row?

```js
 this.columnDefs1 = [ 
    {
         headerName: "M1",
         field: "m1",
         width: 90,
         cellRendererFramework: InputComponent,
         controlData: {
             type: 'text'
         },
    },
]

this.rowData1 = [
    { 
        m1: "50",
    },
    { 
        m1: "30",
    },
    { 
        m1: "",
        //If I don't want input component in this row, how can I remove? 
        //I have tried by not giving m1
        //also but its coming in whole column or every row.
    },
    { 
        m1: "20",
    },
]
```

You can see in the linked image for reference, I don't want the last 4 select components, but I need those rows blank:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `colDef.cellRendererSelector` which is a function that selects the renderer based on the row data

```js
headerName: "M1",
field: "m1",
width: 90,
cellRendererSelector: function (params) { 
    if (params.data.m1) {
       return InputComponent;
    } else {
       return null;
    }
},
controlData: {
    type: 'text'
}
```

You can read more about it here - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/#many-renderers-one-column